Accessing Request Headers on Chrome Console
I am trying to run a script to send a GET request and it requires some headers. I am testing the values on the Browser Console and verifying the values before running the script.
I am using this method to fetch the values.
localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

Console:

Headers:

What am I doing wrong?  How can I access the request headers values
I also checked in the Application/localStorage folder on Chrome, and I don't see these headers. Where else are they stored and how can I fetch them?
I have tried using both localStorage and sessionStorage.

Local storage has nothing to do with headers. It doesn't come from the server, it's managed entirely by JavaScript. I think you're confusing it with cookies.

You are conflating localStorage, which is data saved across browser sessions, sessionStorage which is data stored in a single browser session, and browser headers. Your data is stored in the headers, but you are trying to retrieve them from completely separate storage systems.
To get the headers in JavaScript, use the Headers object.
const myHeaders = new Headers(); // Currently empty
const accessToken = myHeaders.get("accessToken");
const authorizationToken = myHeaders.get("authorizationToken");
const correlationId = ...
// ...

One additional note: you use var which is old JavaScript syntax. Since ES6, released in 2015, variables should use const for those that don't change and let for those that do change.

Thank you for the comment.  Is this also supported for Chrome? I am getting null for using get()

I am trying to access Request Headers.

@NavjotSingh You might need to add information to your question then. Are you talking about the request headers for the webpage that the user loads, or a separate GET request?

I am trying to send a get request and that request requires some headers to send so I was trying to read it out of JS (or out of the DOM) to see if the value actually exist or not to make sure I am not sending a null. As shown in the second picture, you will see the accessToken or authorizationToken value but accessing them returns null.

If I understand correctly, you are making a request to a separate API service that requires these headers. You won't get these headers automatically, you have to obtain them yourself. Then, to set the request headers in the GET request, you attach them when you call the fetch() function (or axios.get()), or whichever function you are using in JavaScript. Normally you obtain the accessToken from the API service website.
If this is not what you mean, please edit your question to be more specific.
